# Border missing in IE10 on page load, it shows after mouse over

Tags: css, border, internet-explorer-10

In IE10, border is not getting displayed on page load, it displays only after I hover over that particular section. Its looking fine in IE9 and Firefox, the issue persists only in IE10.
Unfortunately I couldn't share code as its a restricted internal dev environment.
If anyone of you came across such scenario, please share the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably an Internet Explorer bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar css then you might also know that the issue you have mentioned "displays only after I hover" will occur only when you have put something like the following in css

```
#a : hover
{
border:5px solid white;
}
```

If you haven't mentioned such thing in your Stylesheet or inside html  tags then what @MarioErmando said would be the issue. Try using **F12** Developer tools in IE to check.